# UITableView not working correctly in some simulators, but works in others

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode, uitableview

I'm using a standard `UITableViewController`, when I run the simulator (Xcode 6, Objective-C) as iPhone 4s, 5, 5s or iPad Air it works just fine. But if I change the simulator to iPhone 6, 6+, iPad Retina it doesn't work, no data gets displayed in the table... I'm totally baffled by this. No errors anywhere.

Any ideas?

```
#pragma mark - Table view data source
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
return 1;
}

-(NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section{
    return [self.tableData count];
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"CaseCell" forIndexPath:indexPath];

    // Configure the cell
    cell.textLabel.text = [self.tableData objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

return cell;
}
```

Comment: I had a similar problem. Need to include "numberOfRowsInSection" and set this to 1.

Comment: I fixed it, I wasn't initializing the array correctly in viewDidLoad, doh!